# Loop through list, give second following items class

Tags: jquery, list, loops

I have a list with 3 items, the index/active item changes when clicking an up or down button. I want the first following after the index should have an class 'drain' and the second following after index should get class 'unfill'. So when clicking through it would look like this

when index is 1:

```
 <a href="#" class="active"> Item One </a>
 <a href="#" class="drain"> Item Two </a>
 <a href="#" class="unfill"> Item Three </a>
```

when index is 2:

```
<a href="#" class="unfill"> Item One </a>
<a href="#" class="active"> Item Two </a>
<a href="#" class="drain"> Item Three </a>
```

when index is 3:

```
<a href="#" class="drain"> Item One </a>
<a href="#" class="unfill"> Item Two </a>
<a href="#" class="active"> Item Three </a>
```

My math isn't that good, can somebody help me how this loop would look?

```
var services = $('header.header-image .services-links a');
var totalServices = services.length;
var arrowUp = $('header.header-image .services .pagination .up');
var arrowDown = $('header.header-image .services .pagination .down');

arrowUp.click(function(event) {
 if (index > 1){
   index = index - 1;
 } else {
   index = totalServices;
 }
 updateActiveClass('up');
});

arrowDown.click(function(event) {
 if (index < totalServices){
   index = index + 1;
 } else {
  index = 1;
 }
 updateActiveClass('down');
});

services.click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 thisIndex = $(this).index();
 index =  thisIndex + 1;
 updateActiveClass();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your 'active' class you can set all of the rest to 'unfill' and just next to 'active' with 'drain'. it's not the best solution but should work.

```js
$(function(){

 //cache elements
  var ul = $('ul');
  var lists = $('ul > li');

 $('.up').on('click', function(){
  
    var active = ul.find('.active');
    
    // Remove all classes and set to unfill
    lists.removeClass().addClass('unfill');
    
    // check for next item to set the active class
    if(active.next().length){
     active = active.next().removeClass('unfill').addClass('active');
    }else{
      active = lists.first().removeClass('unfill').addClass('active');
    };
    
    
    // check for next item to set the active drain class
    if(active.next().length){
     active.next().removeClass('unfill').addClass('drain');
    }else{
      lists.first().removeClass('unfill').addClass('drain');
    };
  });
  
 $('.down').on('click', function(){
  
   var active = ul.find('.active');
    
    // Remove all classes and set to unfill
    lists.removeClass().addClass('unfill');
    
    // check for next item to set the active class
    if(active.prev().length){
     active = active.prev().removeClass('unfill').addClass('active');
    }else{
      active = lists.last().removeClass('unfill').addClass('active');
    };
    
    
    // check for next item to set the active drain class
    if(active.next().length){
     active.next().removeClass('unfill').addClass('drain');
    }else{
      lists.first().removeClass('unfill').addClass('drain');
    };
  });
})
```

```css
.active {color: green;}
.drain {color: red;}
.unfill {color: grey;}

.active:after {content: ' active';}
.drain:after {content: ' drain';}
.unfill:after {content: ' unfill';}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">A</li>
  <li class="drain">B</li>
  <li class="unfill">C</li>
  <li class="unfill">D</li>
</ul>

<button class="up">UP</button>
<button class="down">DOWN</button>
```